# How to vectorize row by row multiplication and re-addition in Numpy?

Tags: numpy

Is there a way to remove for loop from this code?

```
for iteration in range(1, 101):
    rs[iteration] += rs[iteration - 1] * adjacency_matrix
```

The `rs` matrix is filled with initial values, and each iteration the vector `rs[iteration]` is calculated using prior iteration multiplied by `adjacency_matrix`

Comment: seem the `rs` matrix store the element-wise powers of `adjacency_matrix` multiplied by the initial value?

Comment: Serial calculations like this are hard to "vectorize".  Normally the compiled `numpy` calculations are 'parallel' - as though all elements were calculated at once, rather than one after the other (even though it iterates in C code).  The `ufunc` `accumlate` methods to this sort of iteration, though.  For example `cumsum`.

Comment: I guess so, it is initially filled with values `(1-beta)/n`, except on row 0 where the initial value is `1/n`, and to those initial values is added `rs[iteration - 1] * adjacency_matrix`.

Comment: Do you have tips how to use ufunc for both multiplication and addition. `cumsum` seems to only cumulatively add.

Comment: This is *not* a python question.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you are just computing a power of the adjacency matrix times the initial conditions. If you just want the result at time 100, then you can do it very quickly using repeated squaring. `100 = 64 + 32 + 4`, and you only need about 5 multiplies. If you want **all** the intermediate results, then if your matrix is symmetric (adjacency matrices often are), then diagonalizing the matrix first is useful.

Comment: The problem is that rs contains initial values, `rs = np.full(shape=(101, n), fill_value=(1 - beta) / n)` , I have to add to that so it is not a straight multiplication.

Comment: @sukisule I don't see how that is relevant. Perhaps you can elaborate.